# Team Foundation Server: New Files

Tags: tfs

We're in the process of evaluating team foundation server for source control. There doesn't seem to be a great way to "discover" that another developer has added file(s) to a solution. Does anyone have any tips to make new files "jump out" a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several alternatives

- There is an option to get the latest version when you open a new solution. (Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> Get everything when a solution or project is opened)
- You can set alerts on a checkin so you see when somebody has checked in files. The easiest way is to install the TFS Power Tools - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f - Then go to the Tools -> Alerts Editor

Another tip is when you want to do the integration of the sources to use Team Build.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the "get latest version" option. Unfortunately, it simply brings up a list of every item in the solution and asks me if I want to get the latest versions. Really, this isn't all that helpful. It's too bad that feature didn't do a quick comparison between the server and your workspace to show you only what has changed. I'll look into the e-mail alerts. E-mails have a tendency to get ignored and forgotten about unless they pertain to a project you're actively working on, but it's better than nothing.